# Generate private and public key from openssl with fips mode enabled

Tags: linux, security, encryption, openssl

I am using openssl (V3). I want to encrypt and decrypt files using fips mode. For that i want to generate private and public key. How ever i am facing difficulty in generating. Command i tried to use here is.

```
 openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.key -aes256 -fips
```

and i am getting

```
genpkey: Unknown cipher: fips
genpkey: Use -help for summary.
80F2D63CB67F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (fips : 0), Properties (<null>)
```

With the error i am unable to understand if openssl is able to use fips140-2 or not.

From my end I have tried  one scenario mentioned in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616573/how-to-check-fips-140-2-support-in-openssl) .

created empty file, and used this command

```
openssl md5 textfile 
Error setting digest
80E2EA90E57F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (MD5 : 100), Properties ()
80E2EA90E57F0000:error:03000086:digital envelope routines:evp_md_init_internal:initialization error:crypto/evp/digest.c:272:
```

Comment: Fips is a standard that restricts algorithms to a specific set, enforces standards on passwords, and a few other things. There is no such algorithm as `fips` so you can’t specify it as one to OpenSSL. The link you posted gave at least two methods to check on FIPS compatibility in OpenSSL. Did either of these work for you?

Comment: @doneal24 yes this the other check i verified ```nm ./usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips
00000000001faff0 T EVP_default_properties_enable_fips
00000000001fae60 T EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enab```

Comment: So the OpenSSL version supports FIPS. If you reboot your system with a kernel option of `fips=1` then you can be confident that you are using approved cyphers.

Comment: one final question @doneal24 now if i generate key pair (public and private) how do i validate it is fips validated key? or if i use weaker security it won't even allow me to create key?

Comment: As described it the linked question, if FIPS mode is enabled, asking a hash that is not approved will generate an error message. A keypair is not something that can be FIPS validated. The software that generates the keypair is what is validated.